# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Backbone TodoList

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, typeerror

I'm following the Todomvc exercise from the Developing BackboneJS Applications book and reached a point to test if what I have so far is working by testing through JavaScript console.

When I type `window.app.Todos.create({ title: 'My first Todo items'});` into the console I get an error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function related to app.js:67. The code there is

```
    addOne: function( todo ) {
        var view = new app.TodoView({ model: todo });
        $('#todo-list').append( view.render().el );
    },
```

I have a few files posted but this is my `Github` repository  https://github.com/gnazarkin/todomvc.

Comment: Likely an import error: Make sure you include your `.js` files in the proper order, `backbone.js` should be included **before** you try to call any methods from it.

Comment: It's hard to say without a plunkr, but I think you forgot a dot your command. Try this: *window.app.Todos.create({ title: 'My first Todo items'});*